# What does my elancer mean when he says this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, meteor

What does it mean if my web designer says this," I built custom site with RoR and rails NodeJs angularJs ember backbone fullstack meteor"?

I wanted him to edit an HTML5 template and after some back and forth that was his response. What do those things mean?

Comment: He is not being very clear in his responses and I want some clarification. Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Mostly, it means he's not a very clear communicator -- that reads like word salad.  That's basically just a list of every JavaScript programming framework that runs on the server side, plus Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I asked him how any of that would benefit the site and he just let me know it had to do with analytics and log in info. Is that the case?

Comment: You don't need any of those things to do analysis of your site traffic (analytics).  They can *help* with that, but that's not their primary purpose.  Those are development frameworks for building applications.  You *do* need those if you want dynamic content (like from a database), or to allow users to create profiles and stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are different programming/scripting languages that he has built websites/apps in... I find it interesting that after telling you about all the JavaScript he has played with he didn't quite say he had the HTML5 experience you are needing. If you can't understand him now you probably wont have any better luck if you hire him to edit the template. You need to find someone you can communicate with efficiently.

Comment: yeah I definitely think that is great advice. He is able to edit the HTML5 but keeps telling me he can add additional analytics and web applications to the site. Not sure what he means at all though since I am not a programmer.

Comment: Analytics such as traffic and where people go and how long they are there can be good to see if people are using the site and more importantly if they are FINDING what they want. This can also be done with google analytics (free for you). He is saying that he can add additional functionality to what you currently have right now. It all depends on what you are looking for (and what you can afford) . He is trying to up-sell you so he has more to do and can make more  money. Be careful that you don't get over charged. Always have everything in writing or emails.

Comment: If I were you, I would not bet that he is able to edit HTML5. Though it is probably a relatively easy task, I'm very certain that you'll receive garbage, although it may seem like he's done the task and that you'll be realizing the negative results down the road when you put your template to use. There are a large number of ways one can edit a template, and a lot of them can be against all best practices, so beware. Better yet, find someone else.

Comment: Yes I am definitely wary. He is being very vague and wants the money up front as well. Not sure if that is common practice for freelancers but I was hoping I could pay after I saw the work.

Comment: NO!!! if you pay anything up front it would be half of the total bill. .. Dont pay completely upfront as he will have no reason to actually do or finish the job. It is pretty customary to even pay after it is all done and everything meets the standards/requirements you gave him. I would move on to someone else so you don't get ripped off. Has he shown you his work? Did he PROVE he did it?

Comment: I can give you my contact info so I can better help you and we dont clutter up this post ;) let me know and i will post and then edit the post to remove my info. I looked and there is not a better way to contact others on here that I have found.

Comment: Yeah I would love to at least email you to get some info.

Comment: received. Go ahead and remove it

Comment: Thank you for being timely! We can continue via email to free up server resources for other postings. Talk to you soon :)